# Front-end app Graphql request blocked by Safari, Firefox, but not Chrome on Heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, graphql, graphql-js

When I deployed my app on Heroku, it works fine on Chrome, but not loading on Firefox and Safari. Heroku Log shows no particular errors:
[Heroku Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2q9p.png)

In the console of Firefox, it says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/graphql. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

This is my setup of the server

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require('./schema/schema');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodburi, { useNewUrlParser: true })

mongoose.connection.once('open', ()=>{
  console.log('Connected to database');
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}));

app.withCredentials = true;

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log(`Now listening requests on port:${port}`);
})
```

Some people seem to say it's a security license issue. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: does it work if you remove this line: app.use(cors()); ?

Comment: Tried it. Did not work...

Comment: your server setups are fine I think, but how do you connect on client-side? it seems that you're using `http://localhost:4000/graphql` try to use heroku url instead.

Comment: I have no idea why it's still call the localhost. On Chrome, the network makes the same request to localhost:4000/graphql, but it works. That's what confused me the most.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue all day and I have just figured out what was wrong.

First I have removed the `localhost` from the `uri` in the frontend as following:

```
// It was "http://localhost:4000/graphql" before 
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' });

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Still in the frontend, I have created an proxy script so it doesn't break the application when in development: (`package.json`)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": { //... },
   // ...,

   // This line below
   "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

And finally in the backend, my `server.js` file is almost exactly as yours except for this line:

```
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
}); 

// This chunk of code is here just as a reference
const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log(`Now listening requests on port:${port}`);
})
```

So, after making those changes I ran `npm run build` again on client side, committed to both github and heroku and it works as a charm.

I hope it helps someone else.